# How to print an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a novice in Java programming. I couldn't catch in the following case why I can't print an array by this line:

```
System.out.print(arr());
```

Instead of all of results I got this: '[D@60e1e567'

What did I do wrong?

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(arr());
    }

    public static double[] arr() {
        double res;

        int count=0;
        double[] anArray = new double[100000000];


        int k=0;
        for (int j=2;j<101;j++){
            for(int i=2; i<101;i++) {
                res=Math.pow(j,i);
                anArray[k]=res;
                k++;
            }
        }

        return anArray;         
    }
}
```

Comment: because you can't just print an array with `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Please note that java has its coding style. Your class should begin with a capital letter.

Comment: @qben , There is no rule in java  that your class name should starts with capital, It may be small or capital

Comment: @Swarnendu see java naming conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367.
Naming conventions are not rules but conventions, of course.

Comment: Thats why it is not necessary to  name your class with a name starts with a Capital letter ....
user user1813163 is a novice so  plz don't confuse him...

Comment: I learnt this right after "Hello world" so I think a novice also should at least know of this.

Answer (score 1):

You cant print arrays like this

```
System.out.print(arr());
```

Use this:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr()));
```

In order to do this you should also add

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

in the beginning of the file

Also your array is to big. `100000000` doubles will probably not fit in array. You probably want to change the Data structure, or limit the size. Otherwise you risk getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: user000001 hm, the compiler says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)

Comment: Do you actually need so many elements? Why not use an `ArrayList` instead? It changes its size dynamically...

Comment: yes, I would use distinct way in order to get a list of all of possible numbers

Comment: Not sure if your combinations fit in main memory. If they do, you can increase the heap space. A tutorial for that is **[here](http://blogs.opcodesolutions.com/roller/java/entry/solve_java_lang_outofmemoryerror_java)**. If they don't, then you will probably have to store your data in a file. But I think this is out of the scope of this question. Maybe you should ask a new one, if these methods don't work for you

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr()));
```

Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(double). Returns "null" if array is null.

Comment: hm, the compiler says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)

Comment: @user1813163 That is not because you are trying to print array. That errror is because of heap space.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the array to see it's values, or call the Collections convenience method which roughly does the same thing: `Arrays.toString(arr())`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] d = arr();
    for(double x : d) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't print arrays directly. 
you need somthing like:

```
double[] array=arr();

for(double x: array)
   System.out.print(x+" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong. Arrays don't implement a nice toString() by default. The best way to print a human-readable output is to use `Arrays.asList(arr())`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing whole array you should print each elements there:

```
double[] resultAry =arr();
for(int i=0; i< resultAry.length; i++ ){
System.out.println(resultAry[i]);
}
```